# InDesign File Missing

Tags: adobe-indesign, file-management, file-recovery

I'm sure of the file location and name, but it isn't there today. InDesign was crashing with an earlier version of the file so I think it deleted the file somehow.

There might be some temporary version. More specifically I was wondering if and how I can recover some information from the cache/InDesign Recovery folder?

Ps. It's a three hour work file. I also tried creating an empty file at the same location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first step you need to take is to verify if InDesign even has any recovery information.

InDesign Recovery folder locations. To find them on `Mac OS X` navigate to

> Users/[User Name]/Library/Cache/Adobe InDesign/Version[#.0]/InDesign Recovery`

And on `Windows`

> Windows Vista and 7: C:\Users[User Name]\AppData\Local\Adobe\InDesign\Version [#].0\en_US\Caches\InDesign Recovery

It should look something like this:

[image]

If you have files there I would shutdown InDesign and restart your computer. When you reopen InDesign see if the recovery process starts. If it doesn't that means that the recovery data doesn't exist, the file doesn't exist or the data is corrupt and you are out of luck.

Comment: Yes I have some files there and it's in them I was hoping. I will try the shutdown.

Comment: No nothing happened after shutdown. So if InDesign doesnt automatically use the cache in recovery there is no way to rename them and somehow get a workable file ..

Comment: Sadly no, they are not actual `InDesign` files but just temporary save files.